# Yahoo Pipes RSS: Copy link to looped results from Twitter search

Tags: twitter, rss, yahoo-pipes

I am using Yahoo pipes to make automated Twitter Searches using terms from the description fields of an RSS feed.

Pipes makes one search from each item in the feed. Each search returns a set of results which are assigned as item.twitloop  (all results)

I would like to replace the link from each item in the results with the link from the original query item;

So far I am only able to assign the original link to the first item in the results list rather than to each item.

http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.edit?_id=01f5f60eb8f3c22b45aa3708e5ae057a

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The pipe isn't loading for me - perhaps you didn't set it as public?  In any event, I have solved similar problems in the past by using the Loop module.  You put the assignment into the loop (usually a string builder works well), and then have the Loop put that original link into item.link.

Comment: The OP is looking to update the fields of one feed (the Twitter searches) with a field of a different feed (the original query). How can this be done with a Loop, which has only one input?

Comment: Loop can take a feed as an input. It only operates on one field of the feed that you specify.